# Is Winter Bash over on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

Why don't I see the hats on my user page? The hat has been removed from my photo as well. Is the Winter Bash over?

Comment: yep, it's over..

Comment: I fail to see how this question is too broad.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Winter Bash is **long** over. See the [Winter Bash FAQ](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/faq):

> From December 15th **until January 4th**, you'll be able to earn hats all over the sites! Ask, answer, vote, edit, and chat, and you'll uncover hats hidden in all kinds of places.

and

> ### What happens after January 4th?
>
> **After January 4th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear**. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

You can still see what hats you earned on the [Winter Bash 2014 site](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/).

Also see the [wrap-up for this year's Bash](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/) on the Stack Overflow Blog.

Comment: It would be nice to see a disclosed list of *undiscovered secret hats*, at least without descriptions for the next year fun experience!

Comment: @skuntsel: there is no such list. See the [wrap-up blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/).

Comment: @skuntsel: my comment may not have been precise enough: there is no such list because all secret hats were discovered. Early on it was clear that the Winter Bash javascript code contained entries for all hats, with the secret hat artwork omitted. There were 8 slots with no artwork, and we found 8 secret hats.

Comment: @skuntsel: also see [Winter Bash 2014 post-mortem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246825) where the project lead admits that the secrets were too easy and all secret hats were found in the first two days.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, that was an interesting read.

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry, [winter bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) is back with its share of nice surprises :-)

[image]

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?

Comment: @DavidG Don't be so grumpy, nobody likes the question anyway :-P