# When exactly will my hats vanish?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

The [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com) page says my hats will be "put back in their boxes on January 4th". The [FAQ](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/faq) at the same page says "After January 3rd, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear."

Combining these two statements, am I to assume that this means "midnight on January 3rd", presumably UTC time?

(This wording is different from [last year's wording](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283687/1270695), by the way.)

Last year, I missed the window to get a screenshot of my hat collection, and I'd be really sad if that happened again :-(

Comment: It'd be nice of SE to provide some hat storage facility so we can look at previous years hats as well.

Comment: Now I think I'm going to need to ask another question to figure out why I haven't gotten my "Field Work" hat for posting this question from the app.... :-(

Comment: Note that "midnight on January 3rd" by itself is also ambiguous ;) Yeah, I know which one you meant, but still.

Comment: Regarding "Field Work": This is a meta question. You don't get anything for meta activity unless the hat specifically mentions it's about meta.